# Не обработалась mini-markdown разметка в автоматическом комментарии

Tags: дефект

Предложил закрытие [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/840239/204271), как дубликата. Система автоматически сгенерировала соответствующий комментарий, но разметка в комментарии не обработалась, и комментарий выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Закрывающую круглую скобку потеряли? Или длины комментария не хватило для нее

Comment: Я не писал этот комментарий, его сгенерировал сам движок SO.